# Lazy suspended tail in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I was going through some notes and I realized something is amiss.

When emulating lazy computation (without `open Lazy;`) one can do the following for a stream of ones.

```
datatype 'a susp = Susp of (unit -> 'a)

datatype 'a stream' = Cons of 'a * ('a stream') susp
type 'a stream = ('a stream') susp

fun delay (f ) = Susp(f);

fun force  (Susp(f)) = f ();

val rec ones' = fn () => Cons(1, delay(ones'));

val ones = delay(ones')

fun ltail(Susp(s)) = ltail'(force s)   
and ltail' (Cons(x,s)) = s
```

But for getting a suspended tail the types do not match up.

```
operator domain: 'Z susp   
operand:         unit -> 'Y
```

What will need to change for the proper types for ltail ?
I know what happens with a tail not suspended.
I just want to figure out what the notes were saying for the suspended version.

Comment: Interesting language. Never heard of it. Since when does NJ get their own language and Texas doesn't? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun ltail(Susp(s)) = ltail'(force s)
```

The problem here is that `force` takes a value of type `susp`, but you call it with a value of type `() -> 'a`. I.e. you take the function out of the `susp` value and then call `force` on the function instead of the `susp` value. You should just do:

```
fun ltail s = ltail' (force s)
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that when I sat down with the notes , though I wasn't sure why it was with Susp(s) in the notes. Oh well ... I will assume it was a typo and life moves on.